# getElementsByTagName is not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I want to get all the child elements from the row.

Javascript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
var row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
```

The corresponding HTML is 
    
        
            
            :
            
            :
            
            :
            
        
    
    var tab = document.getElementById("tableID");
    var Row = tab.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
when Intry to get Row.cells IE8 returns undefined.If I use this code locally It works fine.But Am using xsl code.

Comment: What do you mean by *blank value*? Any errors in your console?

Comment: <tr>
<td><input id="1" type="text"  style="width:46px;"></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input id="2" type="text"  style="width:46px;"></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input id="3" type="text"  style="width:46px;"></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input id="1" type="text"  style="width:46px;"></td>
</tr>

Comment: I need a format as IP address...If I get the length of row like row.cells.length the value will be blank.In Firefox its coming as 7

Comment: What element do you think is assigned to `table`?

Answer (score 2):

This

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
```

Returns your actual tr.

So for it to be ok you should do:

```
var row = table.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll)). It'll *even* work in IE8:

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID td');
```